# Can't copy ".htm" file to another folder in Arduino

Tags: arrays, c, arduino, copy

I want to copy ".htm" file which is in SD Card, from A to B. Is the read and write only way to copy it or am i able to make it easier and safer.

I tried to copy the file first but there is more than 500k letters/characters, it doesnt fit in any variable type i know.
Edit: i tried to copy file with the read and write but there is still sth wrong with output, i will shortly show you in some code lines. When i increase the CHUNK_SIZE my display starting to flash for 2 seconds and opening back again, copying process is also not working. Right now it takes 20 seconds to copy 500kb file,

```
        loop : `
            #define CHUNK_SIZE 3000
            void readFileHTM() {
              String filePath = "asdfg.htm";
              File file = SD.open(filePath, FILE_READ);
              byte buffer[CHUNK_SIZE];
              size_t bytes_read;
              size_t bytes_written;
             while ((bytes_read = file.read(buffer, CHUNK_SIZE)) > 0) {
                // Remove STX character from the beginning of the buffer
                if (buffer[0] == 0x02) {
                  for (size_t i = 0; i < bytes_read - 1; i++) {
                    buffer[i] = buffer[i+1];
                  }
                  bytes_read--;
                }
//this STX characters shows up when you just copy and paste the text, i had to remove them to get clear copy of the file

            // Write the data in the buffer to the new file
            String filePath1 = G_DIRECTORY_NAME + "ASDFG.htm";
            File file1 = SD.open(filePath1, FILE_WRITE);
            file1.write(buffer, bytes_read);
            //close the file
            file1.close();
        }
    }
        `
    
    //in this code i have also some additional fixes like "removing any non-printable characters from the buffer, Add newline character after every ';' in the buffer " and finally i got my result but result is in only 1 line.
```

Comment: File copying is usually done using a loop that reads/writes chunks, not everything at once.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show your code. Normally you copy a file by reading and writing blocks of data in a loop. I'm sure you will find examples here with the search function.

Comment: Is [`std::filesystem::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy) available on Arduino? Arduino uses C++ after all, not C.

Comment: @Gerhardh Now that seems to be a useful function.

Comment: Arduino does not have a file system by default. Please [edit] your question and add details about the file system where the ".htm" file is stored.

Comment: yes i found some examples of course and already completed the algorithm but last problem is, whole code just coming in 1 line, "\n" is not working and i couldnt understand why

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself,  "solved" to your question title or body.. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It really was solved in a different way. I wrote another function that deletes "any" character in "A.htm" and creates "B.htm". The thing is, if you give the delete function a character that isn't in your code, it won't delete any part of the file and create exactly the same file. You need to add delete functionality to your copy function, for example:

```
void readFileHTM() {
deleteFunction();

//keep the read/write code in here as it is 
}
```